# C# using linq how to insert data in a column

Tags: c#, linq

I want to fill a column with random numbers in sql  using linq ? 
how can I do that?

Comment: I guess by writing proper code, compiling and executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of details, this may be a solution:

```
    Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Milliseconds);

    using (var context = new Data.Entities())
    {
        var entries = context.YourTable;

        foreach (var entry in entries ) 
        {
           entry.YourColumn = random.Next(100);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: it's working but when I go back to the database i don't find what I inserted, What should I do ?

Comment: Show us the code you've wrote for DB insertion

Comment: Random rnd = new Random();                                                                                                            

            using (var context = new saherEntities())
            {
                var entries = context.Employees;
                foreach (var entry in entries)
                {
                  entry.Name = Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(100));
                }
                context.SaveChanges();

Comment: And the column associated to the Name property is not updated? No errors are being thrown?

Comment: yes the column in the database is not updated , and no errors are being thrown.

Comment: I'm going to need more context. Can you show me the entire code? E.g. on pastebin or dotnetfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use c# random class

```
Random rnd = new Random();
   int val = rnd.Next(1,100);
```

than create your object to insert in concerned table using linq.

```
YourObject obj= new YourObject
{
    Objval = val, 
    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
    // …
};
```

// Add the new object to the Orders collection.

```
yourdb.YourObjects.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
```

than you  Submit the change to the database

```
yourdb.SubmitChanges();
```